# DateTime.Compare how to check if a date is less than 30 days old?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to work out if an account expires in less than 30 days. Am I using DateTime Compare correctly?

```
if (DateTime.Compare(expiryDate, now) < 30)

{
     matchFound = true;
}
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

> Am I using DateTime Compare correctly?

No. `Compare` only offers information about the relative position of two dates: less, equal or greater. What you want is something like this:

```
if ((expiryDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 30)
    matchFound = true;
```

This subtracts two `DateTime`s. The result is a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(VS.80).aspx) object which has a `TotalDays` property.

Additionally, the conditional can be written directly as:

```
bool matchFound = (expiryDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 30;
```

No `if` needed.

Alternatively, you can avoid naked numbers by using `TimeSpan.FromDays`:

```
bool matchFound = (expiryDate - DateTime.Now) < TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
```

This is slightly more verbose but I generally recommend using the appropriate types, and the appropriate type in this case is a `TimeSpan`, not an `int`.

Comment: Should be allowed to give you 2+ ;) one for the answer and one for the short way to express it

Comment: Uh … I just made my answer longer so feel free to subtract one imaginary vote. ;-)

Comment: Please use [`TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) instead of days.

Comment: @João Why? It makes no difference in this case.

Comment: It is conceptually more accurate. It makes no difference because `Days` is the biggest component of `TimeSpan`. People reading this can extrapolate that to think that the `Seconds` property works the same way.

Comment: @João Hmm. Agreed. Will change.

Comment: Adding to the point João Portela made, even `Days` itself can be wrong too. `Days` and `TotalDays` are the same here only because the condition is `< 30`, but there would be an obvious difference if it was `<= 30`, because `TotalDays` may returns something like `30.421` while `Days` still returns `30`.

Answer (score 17):

should be

```
matchFound = (expiryDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 30;
```

note the total days
otherwise you'll get werid behaviour

Comment: this answer was over a year after the last edit to accepted answer!

Comment: @Mitch - This is the correct answer, notice he is using TotalDays rather than Days.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. TotalDays returns a fractional portion as well, which is redundant when comparing to an integer.

Comment: @MitchWheat `TotalDays` is **conceptually** correct field to use. In practice they give the same result but only because `Days` is the biggest component of `TimeSpan`, had there been a Months or Years component and this would have been a different story. Just try with `Hours`, `Seconds` or `Milliseconds` to see how they work.

Answer (score 7):

Well I would do it like this instead:

```
TimeSpan diff = expiryDate - DateTime.Today;
if (diff.Days > 30) 
   matchFound = true;
```

Compare only responds with an integer indicating weather the first is earlier, same or later...

Answer (score 5):

Try this instead

```
if ( (expiryDate - DateTime.Now ).TotalDays < 30 ) { 
  matchFound = true;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you need to either invert the order of your dates or take the absolute value, unless the expiration date is already passed.

Answer (score 3):

Compare returns 1, 0, -1 for greater than, equal to, less than, respectively.

You want:

```
    if (DateTime.Compare(expiryDate, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)) <= 0) 
    { 
        bool matchFound = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you accurate result :

```
if ((expiryDate.Date - DateTime.Now.Date).Days < 30)
    matchFound = true;
```

Comment: actually what happens hr is eg.expryDte is 28/4/2011 if U rite (expiryDate-DateTime.now) it will take the time as well (28/4/2011 12:00:00 AM - 26/4/2011 11:47:00 AM) & above code takes value as 28/4/2011 12:00:00 AM -26/4/2011 12:00:00 AM which ill give accurate difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to assign `false` (if applicable) to `matchtime`, a simpler way of writing it would be..

```
matchtime = ((expiryDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 30);
```

Comment: The ternary operator here is completely redundant as ((expiryDate - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 30) already returns a boolean.

Comment: @Fabio Thanks buddy removed them to assign the Boolean value via the return type.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Compare function will return either 1, 0, or -1. 0 when the two values are equal, -1 and 1 mean less than and greater than, I believe in that order, but I often mix them up.

Answer (score 0):

No you are not using it correctly.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) for details.

```
DateTime t1 = new DateTime(100);
DateTime t2 = new DateTime(20);

if (DateTime.Compare(t1, t2) >  0) Console.WriteLine("t1 > t2"); 
if (DateTime.Compare(t1, t2) == 0) Console.WriteLine("t1 == t2"); 
if (DateTime.Compare(t1, t2) <  0) Console.WriteLine("t1 < t2");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is subtract the two DateTimes (expiryDate and DateTime.Now).  This will return an object of type TimeSpan.  The TimeSpan has a property "Days".  Compare that number to 30 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not correct, try this :

```
DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-31);
if (DateTime.Compare(expiryDate, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)) < 1)
{
    matchFound = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of these answers worked for me. I solved it by doing like this:

```
  if ((expireDate.Date - DateTime.Now).Days > -30)
  {
    matchFound = true;
  }
```

When i tried doing this:

```
matchFound = (expiryDate - DateTime.Now).Days < 30;
```

Today, 2011-11-14 and my expiryDate was 2011-10-17 i got that matchFound = -28. Instead of 28. So i inversed the last check.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this isn't set up for good processing.  
//I don't know what data set has the expiration 
//dates of your accounts.  I assume a list.
// matchfound is a single variablethat returns true if any 1 record is expired.

bool matchFound = false;
            DateTime dateOfExpiration = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
            List<DateTime> accountExpireDates = new List<DateTime>();
            foreach (DateTime date in accountExpireDates)
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(dateOfExpiration, date) != -1)
                {
                    matchFound = true;
            }
            }
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit complicated?

Comment: Where is the mention of accountExpireDates in the question? You copy pasted a bad solution. matchFound almost sounds like you're mixing Pattern or RegEx. Btw, you need to break when a match is found or it continues to loop. Also what if it is -2? MSDN does not say the possible values are -1, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this:

```
var daysPassed = (DateTime.UtcNow - expiryDate).Days;
if (daysPassed > 30)
{ 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive in your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

**Compare** is unnecessary, **Days** / **TotalDays** are unnecessary.

All you need is

```
if (expireDate < DateTime.Now) {
    // has expired
} else {
    // not expired
}
```

note this will work if you decide to use minutes or months or even years as your expiry criteria.

Comment: Not a great answer because now you are also factoring in hours, minutes and seconds. DateTime.Today would be more correct for the OPs situation.