# Delete files older than a date

Tags: c#, datetime, logging

I am currently working on a c# program where I check the creation time of a file and delete it if the file is older than 2 days. I have the following code snippet that should be achieving this.

```
DateTime creationTime = file.CreationTime.Date;
if (creationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-logAge) && file.Name != currentLog)
{
    File.Delete(string.Format("{0}/{1}", directory, file));
}
```

While my program is running it is constantly creating new files and a separate thread checks that the files are no older than say 2 days. If I have my PC's date set to the 24th April the files are created and kept as expected, if I then change the PC's date to the 25th April I would expect the files to remain as they are not older than 2 days, however, this is not the case as they are being deleted.

Log age is set to so I wouldn't have expected files to be deleted until after I had changed the date to be the 26th April.

What am I doing wrong, I've looked at many examples including another question on Stackoverflow [Delete files older than 3 months old in a directory using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222348/how-to-delete-files-older-than-3-months-old-in-a-directory-using-net) but its not doing what I would expect it to.

Comment: Btw this string.Format("{0}/{1}", directory, file) is weird. We have nice library for this: System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, file)

Comment: And in addition to @jing, in this case all you need is `file.Delete()` (note the lower-case `f`)

Comment: How do you test this change-the-date? With the program running?

Comment: Oh, I see it @Henk. file is obviously of type FileSystemInfo. So file.Delete() is the correct usage.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm testing it by changing the computers date setting while the program is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.Delete does make more sense than File.Delete(path) and Path.Combine() makes a lot more sense than using string.Format.

I've stumbled across this answer, don't know why I didn't find it before hand after spending ages on google, but this appears to have fixed the problem. [DateTime.Compare how to check if a date is less than 30 days old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528368/datetime-compare-how-to-check-if-a-date-is-less-than-30-days-old). The other problem was that I was using the file creation time but for my scenario it made more sense to use lastWriteTime.date.

Answer (score 9):

You forced to consider only the date part of the creation time-stamp then condition is satisfied and file will be deleted (earlier) anyway I suggest a few modifications to that code:

```
static class Helpers {
    public static void DeleteOldFiles(string folderPath, uint maximumAgeInDays,
                                      params string[] filesToExclude) {
        DateTime minimumDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-maximumAgeInDays);

        var filesToDelete = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
            .Where(x => !IsExcluded(x, filesToExclude));

        foreach (var eligibleFileToDelete in filesToDelete)
            DeleteFileIfOlderThan(eligibleFileToDelete, minimumDate);
    }

    private const int RetriesOnError = 3;
    private const int DelayOnRetry = 1000;

    private static bool IsExcluded(string item, string[] exclusions) {
        return exclusions.Contains(item, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    private static void DeleteFileIfOlderThan(string path, DateTime date)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RetriesOnError; ++i) {
            try {
                var file = new FileInfo(path);
                if (file.CreationTime < date)
                    file.Delete();
            }
            catch (IOException) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DelayOnRetry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm still using `DateTime.Now`, I guess for this kind of operations you do not need any precision measurement (and you're talking about days so your thread may have a scheduled time of **hours**).
- If your application uses multiple log files you can specify them all as parameters and they'll be ignored.
- If you call `DeleteOldFiles` with 0 for `maximumAgeInDays` then you'll delay all log files not in use (as specified in the exclusion list).
- Sometimes files can be in use (even if this should happen seldom in your case). The `DeleteFileIfOlderThan` function will retry to delete them after a short delay (it mimics `Explorer.exe` behavior).

You can call this function in this way:

```
Helpers.DeleteOldFiles(@"c:\mypath\", logAge, currentLog);
```

Few more notes:

- This code doesn't combine path and file name but if you have to do it you should use `Path.Combine()`, I guess you do not want to reinvent the wheel each time to check if a path ends with a trailing backslash or not.
- I/O operations can fail! Always check for exceptions.

Comment: What's about deleting large files, any sample using Threading, BackgroundWorker, ...?

Comment: @Kiquenet code itself is pretty straightforward, if you need a check about size then simply add it (eventually replacing timestamp check). I don't think you need a background worker for this (unless this is a task started by UI and you also want to give some feedback to user). In that case I'd add a callback parameter to DeleteOldFiles(), in your b.w. you invoke DeleteOldFiles() and you keep UI notified using such callback. Instead if it's just for "cleaning purposes" it may be a scheduled operation on a long time running low priority background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess an additional problem must be in

```
File.Delete(string.Format("{0}/{1}", directory, file));
```

Your **file** is of type ***FileSystemInfo***. Maybe you wanted to use **file.Name**. 
Example: let's say *directory* is "c:\" and *file* points to "c:\myfile.log", your code will try to delete "***c:/c:\myfile.log***". It's hard for me to guess what exactly you have in these variables.

Correct replacement is suggested by @HenkHolterman:

```
file.Delete();
```