# How to find out if a file was created more than a month ago from the present time?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to add files that were created a month ago in list. 
Like this:

```
if (f.CreationTime.Date < DateTime.Now) 
    fileNames.Add(f.Name);
```

But i don't undertand how to check this condition correctly.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295561/delete-files-older-than-a-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (f.CreationTime.Date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
{
   fileNames.Add(f.Name);
}
```

Comment: what is f ? you have just copy pasted with `.AddMonths(-1)` for what op has asked

Comment: @Lucifer from OP's question "*created a month ago*" hence `.AddMonths(-1)`

Comment: 'f' is the file in OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *Linq*: let's filter out all the required files' names and then add them with a help of `AddRange`

```
  // Date to compare with
  DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

  fileNames.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyFiles") //TODO: put the right path
    .EnumerateFiles() //TODO: Provide a filter (say, "*.txt") if required
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime < compareDate)
    .Select(file => file.Name));
```

If `fileNames` has nothing to preserve you create it:

```
  DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

  List<string> fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyFiles") //TODO: put the right path
    .EnumerateFiles() //TODO: Provide a filter (say, "*.txt") if required
    .Where(file => file.CreationTime < compareDate)
    .Select(file => file.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Lovely solution, it's crazy how LINQ simplifies everything

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the last Creation date using [`File.GetCreationDate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    DateTime filedate = File.GetCreationTime(@"sample.txt");
    int res = DateTime.Compare(filedate,DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
    if(res == -1 || res == 0)
    {
       //do your task
    }
```

Comment: There's a `)` missing at the end of your second line of code, right before `;`

Comment: @Lucifer Microsoft has also implemented the [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_lessthan(v=vs.90).aspx) '<' and '>'. So you use these to compare two dates, no point in using DateTime.Compare

Comment: thanks rafalon added it

Comment: @alexandreBEaudet see lin's comment in this{https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059628/6947385} answer

Comment: Since he didn't add his code or anything, can't really take his comment for a sure thing. Been using, as probably most of the other c# dev, the operator and never failed me

Comment: why to increase time complexity - by comparing dates ( `res = DateTime.Compare(d1,d2)`) and then check for comparison result ( `if(res == 1)` )  when you can direct compare (`if (d1 > d2)` \) dates ?